# How can I graph a log file using a regex

Tags: graphs, regex

I have a log file containing lines like this one every minutes :

```
[2015-02-13 14:29:53.2160][INF] [12] Memory : Total=370,000;Managed=120,000
```

I am looking for a tool that takes a (several) log file and a regular expression to graph the memory usage from the log file.

I am not looking for the regular expression but the application.
(The regex would be )

```
^\[(.{24})*\]\[INF\] \[12\] Memory : Total=([^;]*);Managed=([^\s]*)
```

**Notes**:

- I don't care actually about what OS the tool should run on, Windows, Linux, Browser ...
- I am willing to use command line on amiga if it does the tricks.

Comment: Command line or GUI? Any other specific requirements? Graph in live-view, or interactive-on-demand – or exporting files, generating some (static) HTML? Keeping history for a given time (RRD comes to my mind here), or just keeping some "snapshots"? The more exact you can describe it, the better the answers would match your expectations :)

Answer (score 1):

Given your willingness to use command-line on Amiga, I can think of a solution involving multiple tools. As already indicated in one of my comments on the question, [RRD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-Robin_Database) is something used regularly for these kind of graphs. There's **[RRDTool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/)** available for many platforms which, with a little programming around, should give pretty good results – and *can be easily integrated in shell scripts, perl, python, ruby, lua or tcl applications.* (quoting the site itself).

To prepare the data, you already pointed to regular expressions use. So in a first step, [Sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) can be used to create a CSV file for *RRDTool* input:

```
sed 's/regexp/replacement/g' inputFileName > outputFileName
```

[image: RRDTool example] [image: RRDTool example]
<sup>Example graphs created by *RRDTool* (source: [RRDTool homepage](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-Robin_Database); click images for larger variants)</sup>

For details, let me refer you to [RRDTool tutorials](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/tut/index.en.html) and [documentation](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/index.en.html).